# VS C++ 6.0 with sqlite *.dll

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, visual-c++

I'm total noob in VS usage, especially in 6.0 version. I want to create first project in C++ that uses sqlite library. Firstly I downloaded *.dll file from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Now I want to use its library in project. Here's my simple code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I add this *.dll file to make sqlite3.h file visible?

---

UPDATE 1

I downloaded amalgamation file and added *.c and *.h file to project like that:

[image]

But I'm getting errors and many of warnings:

```
    --------------------Configuration: DBApp - Win32 Debug--------------------
Compiling...
StdAfx.cpp
Compiling...
DBApp.cpp
C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\ADMINISTRATOR\MOJE DOKUMENTY\POBIERANIE\DBApp\DBApp.cpp(6) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
Compiling...
sqlite3.c
c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(238) : warning C4005: 'SQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE' : macro redefinition
        c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(234) : see previous definition of 'SQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE'
c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(253) : warning C4005: 'SQLITE_MAX_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE' : macro redefinition
        c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(249) : see previous definition of 'SQLITE_MAX_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE'
c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(283) : warning C4005: 'SQLITE_MAX_TRIGGER_DEPTH' : macro redefinition
        c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(281) : see previous definition of 'SQLITE_MAX_TRIGGER_DEPTH'

 ...

c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(105419) : warning C4005: 'MIN' : macro redefinition
        c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(45386) : see previous definition of 'MIN'
c:\documents and settings\administrator\moje dokumenty\pobieranie\sqlite-src\sqlite3.c(108807) : fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header directive
Generating Code...
Error executing cl.exe.

DBApp.exe - 2 error(s), 232 warning(s)
```

Comment: "How can I add this *.dll file to make studio.h file visible?" What?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, now it's corrected. I meant sqlite3.h

Comment: The DLL does not make the header visible.  You likely have to add it to the project's "include headers" path.   As an aside, you should try to use a compiler made more recently than VS6.  From a C++ language perspective it's rather broken and there are a multitude of better alternatives, like http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

Comment: Also, instead of pulling the DLL build, just pull the amalgamation which has a single .c file and the associated .h file.  Much easier IMO to work with.

Comment: I have no impact which version of VS to use. I have to use 6.0

Comment: 1. Disable precompiled headers on the sqlite.c file.  2. Change `#include <sqlite3.h>` to `#include "sqlite3.h"`  3. You do not need to add sqlite3ext.h.  Please read the sqlite docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some path to your VisualC6 project (DBApp.dsp)

Includes, like this to include Java 7 includes (it's an example, you don't need Java) :
[image]

And the libraries, again an example with Java VM (jvm.lib/dll)
[image]

To show this dialog press Alt-F7